# Questions on makefile: "CFLAGS" and "SHVER"?

Tags: makefile

In a makefile, I found the author stated that

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC
SHVER = 2
```

what are the functionalities for these two lines?

Here is the makefile in full:

```
CXX ?= g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC
SHVER = 2

all: svm-train svm-predict svm-scale

lib: svm.o
    $(CXX) -shared -dynamiclib svm.o -o libsvm.so.$(SHVER)

svm-predict: svm-predict.c svm.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-predict.c svm.o -o svm-predict -lm
svm-train: svm-train.c svm.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-train.c svm.o -o svm-train -lm
svm-scale: svm-scale.c
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-scale.c -o svm-scale
svm.o: svm.cpp svm.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c svm.cpp
clean:
    rm -f *~ svm.o svm-train svm-predict svm-scale libsvm.so.$(SHVER)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just makefile variables. `CFLAGS` is a commonly used variable which contains flags that will be passed to the C compiler (e.g. gcc). Makefile variables get expanded later, so when you see e.g.

```
svm.o: svm.cpp svm.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c svm.cpp
```

this will get expanded to:

```
g++ -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC -c svm.cpp
```

Similarly `SHVER` is a shared library version number, so in the case of this dependency and build command:

```
lib: svm.o
    $(CXX) -shared -dynamiclib svm.o -o libsvm.so.$(SHVER)
```

this will get expanded to:

```
g++ -shared -dynamiclib svm.o -o libsvm.so.2
```

Comment: It might be the shell version (SHVER)

Comment: @Dimitri: yes - could be - without seeing the rest of the makefile it's hard to guess how it's being used.

Answer (score 0):

CFLAGS is a make variable name widely used to hold options to be passed to the compiler

SHVER is a less used variable name but it usually holds the version number of a shared library that is to be used (or generated) in the make process (SH is for shared, VER for version)