# How to understand this Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am new to "Make". With respect to the following Makefile:

```
CXX ?= g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC
SHVER = 2

all: svm-train svm-predict svm-scale

lib: svm.o
  $(CXX) -shared -dynamiclib svm.o -o libsvm.so.$(SHVER)

svm-predict: svm-predict.c svm.o
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-predict.c svm.o -o svm-predict -lm
svm-train: svm-train.c svm.o
   $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-train.c svm.o -o svm-train -lm
svm-scale: svm-scale.c
   $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-scale.c -o svm-scale
svm.o: svm.cpp svm.h
   $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c svm.cpp
clean:
  rm -f *~ svm.o svm-train svm-predict svm-scale libsvm.so.$(SHVER)
```

How to understand the process flow of this Makefile? For example, what does "all" and "lib" do here? How to analyze

```
$(CXX) -shared -dynamiclib svm.o -o libsvm.so.$(SHVER)
```

Comment: Some of this is already covered in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487833/questions-on-makefile-cflags-and-shver

Comment: Try reading a tutorial, or the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `make` rule works in the same way.  If any of the dependencies (the values on the right hand side of the `:`) are out of date, they're rebuilt, and then the recipe for the rule is run.  In this case, the `all` target doesn't have a recipe, so `make` just checks the dependencies (`svm-train`, `svm-predict`, and `svm-scale`) and builds them if they're out of date.

The `lib` target is similar - `svm.o` is built if it's out of date, and then the recipe

```
$(CXX) -shared -dynamiclib svm.o -o libsvm.so.$(SHVER)
```

is run.  Since that's the line you asked about analyzing, the `$(CXX)` and `$(SHVER)` are `make` variables that will get filled in as they were defined earlier.  In your case, `$(CXX)` is `g++` and `$(SHVER)` is `2`.  THe command that will get run is:

```
g++ -shared -dynamiclib svm.o -o libsvm.so.2
```

At least assuming you haven't defined `$(CXX)` elsewhere - the `?=` operator used to make that assignment only works if the variable hasn't already been defined.

When you type `make` at the command line, you should see every command on the standard output as it is executed.  You can use `make -d` or `make -n` for more debugging/logging information.

The [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is extremely well written, and is IMHO one of the greatest programming resources available on the web.

Answer (score 3):

If you type

```
$ make all
```

it will build all the things to the right of `all :`, such as svm-train, svm-predict, and svm-scale

```
$(CXX) -shared -dynamiclib svm.o -o libsvm.so.$(SHVER)
```

is the specific rule to build the target lib and it will translate to

```
g++ -shared -dynamiclib svm.o -o libsvm.so.2
```

depending on the values of the variables CXX and SHVER.

Answer (score 1):

The lines for targets `all` and `lib` are called *dependencies*.

The target `all` *depends on* targets `svm-train`, `svm-predict` and `svm-scale`.

The target `lib` *depends on* `lib.o`.

Make follows all these dependencies and then decides which build commands need to be executed.

If you type **make all** then make will try to ensure that targets `svm-train`, `svm-predict` and `svm-scale` are all up to date. make will then recursively examine the dependencies for these targets until it exhausts all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

the `all` trigger solves all the dependencies(access the triggers mentioned): `svm-train` `svm-predict` `svm-scale`

Now, each of that trigger runs that like of script, meaning: compile `svm.o`, using the compiler declared in `CXX` with the flags `-shared` `-dynamiclib`, outputing the file named `libsvm.so.$(SHVER)` (where `$(SHVER)` will be replaced with `2` in your case)